# Test directive using an expression wrapper function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have to test a directive depending on a parent scope function for its initialisation:

```
.directive('droppedSnippet', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'views/dropped-snippet.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            get: '&'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            var s = scope.get({id: attrs.id});
            element.find('.title').text(s.title);
        }
    };
});
```

**Context, skip if in a hurry:** In order to make it easier to imagine (and to discuss the whole idea if you want), on a drop event this directive is added to the document. The directive represents an embed code. During linking the directive, knowing only its `id`, should fetch its content from a controller and fill its markup.

In order to mock the parent scope created by the controller, i set up the following mock:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.foo = function() {
        return {
            title: 'test title',
            code: 'test <code>'
        };
    };
    spyOn(scope, 'foo').andCallThrough();
    element = angular.element('<dropped-snippet id="3" get="foo(id)"></dropped-snippet>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
}));

it('calls the scope function', function() {
    expect(scope.foo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
});
```

The test fails, `scope.foo` is not called. The code works on the server though. I can not find similar examples around. Is this the right way to mock a function in the parent scope?

Comment: do `console.log('foo' in scope)`, if it returns `false` then `foo `function doesn't exist in the `scope` object

Answer (score 1):

Try `expect(scope.foo).toHaveBeenCalledWith("3");`

Or cast it as a number, the @ treats it as a String

Comment: This is the best answer in the world. Why does this not have 10000 upvotes :(?